# My wifi adapter does't work

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie

i am using raspberry pi 2 debian jessie ,my problem is that my wifi adapter does't work ,so i followed [this tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)  edit my /etc/network/interfaces like this `

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
  2 # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
  3 source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
  4
  5 # uncomment the next 4 lines and set the correct wpa-ssid (network ssid) and
  6
  7 #iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  8
  9 auto eth0
 10 iface eth0 inet static
 11         address 192.168.5.104
 12         netmask 255.255.255.0
 13         gateway 192.168.5.5
 14         Bcast 192.168.5.255
 15
 16 allow-hotplug wlan0
 17 iface wlan0 inet static
 18         address 192.168.5.103
 19         netmask 255.255.255.0
 20         gateway 192.168.5.5
 21         Bcast 192.168.5.255
 22         wpa-ssid "YSR 3"
 23         wpa-psk "5588881234"
```

then disable dhcp and enable network and reboot , but i am still facing the same issue .but in tutorial he wrote   systemctl stop dhcpcd.service at first  when i tried i got this
  systemctl stop dhcpcd.service
    Failed to stop dhcpcd.service: Unit dhcpcd.service not loaded

.

`

Comment: i saw this( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address) before it does't help me

Comment: You have not actually said what you did (besides, "I tried everything") or exactly what the problem is.  You've just cut and pasted 2 files -- did you change either of them at all? If so, how?  "Doesn't work" is not very informative.  What are you doing in order to get connected?  What happens?  Etc.  **[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)** <- "Oh please help me me please!" ...Does not get you very far.

Comment: Sorry if that is a bit harsh, but understand that we probably get 5 or 10 "My internet won't work" questions a week.  *Many or most of them are just ignored,* and they usually boil down to someone **not** really having read or paid attention to something in, e.g., the duplicate question above.  So if you want help, you will have to make an effort to isolate the problem or **explicitly indicate** some element of existing documentation that you don't understand.  Right now, I don't see any evidence that you actually have read and followed the instructions in the duplicate.

Comment: my exact problem is that my wifi doesn't work i can't connect to the internet with wifi adapter i am confused there are a lot of  tutorials dhcp client, dhcp server . i don't know what i have to do to get my wifi works . tell me what information exactly you need ?

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you tried, or if you are confused about something, ask specifically about that.  Simply saying you have read all of the hundreds or thousands of tutorials online about connecting to the internet w/ linux (or a raspberry pi) and then basically asking someone to write you *another one* is a waste of time.  Enough have been written already.  There is no reason for someone else to spend their time writing yet another one -- particularly for someone who says none of the others worked for them.

Comment: way you so angry if you don't wanna help me , so it is ok ,

Comment: i tried to stop dhcp and active the old way (systemctl enable networking) and set up my /etc/network/interfaces ,then reboot .but nothing happened